# mysql and php syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting MYSQL Error and My 1uery is:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `".TBL_DEVICE."` WHERE DEV_STATUS='1' $where ORDER BY DEV_TYPE ASC";
```

Error is as follows

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ORDER BY DEV_TYPE ASC' at line 1
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM `device` WHERE DEV_STATUS='1' AND DEV_ID = ORDER BY DEV_TYPE ASC
> ```

Comment: "AND DEV_ID = ORDER" - you're missing a value there..

Comment: `WHERE DEV_STATUS='1' AND DEV_ID = ORDER BY` is obviously wrong. The problem is wherever you're setting `$where`. It's getting the value `AND DEV_ID =`, but that's clearly not everything that should be there. As it is, you haven't posted enough code. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: check $where it does not print the proper value.

Comment: @AdrianM. No, he should fix the code that sets `$where`.

Comment: Also, this code could be a subject of SQL injection. Please never use string contatenation in SQL queries and use prepared statements.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: So firstly i didnt write this code, im just trying to fix it.. the same code works correctly on another server but im trying to rebuild it... 

i believe the $where is defined earlier in the file as;

$check_dev_detail = array();
   $where = array(
           'DEV_TYPE' => $type,
           'DEV_STATUS !=' => '9',
    );
   $check_dev_detail = $this->common_model->get_single_data('*',TBL_DEVICE,$where);
   if(count($check_dev_detail) == '0')
   {

Comment: you need to update / edit your question with your full cod, and not put that in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a value to - DEV_ID

```
SELECT * FROM `device` WHERE DEV_STATUS='1' AND DEV_ID = '*add here*' ORDER BY DEV_TYPE ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least you printed it out, something most people don't do, and something that makes 97% of these problems obvious :-)

```
SELECT * FROM `device` WHERE DEV_STATUS='1' AND DEV_ID = ORDER BY ...
                                            \__________/
                                               $where
```

Your `$where` variable appears to be incomplete in that it contains `AND DEV_ID =` but *without* what you want to compare it with.

You need to fix the code that generates that `where` sub-clause so that the resulting query is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is no clear enough for me, but in your sql code

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_DEVICE." WHERE DEV_STATUS='1' $where ORDER BY DEV_TYPE ASC";
```

why you are using `$where` variable?? and what is it's expected value?

The basic Structure for select all data from a table is :

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = desire_id";
```

**Hope this help**

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your variable "$where" has this value => "AND DEV_ID =".

> $where = "AND DEV_ID =";

first: complete your variable "$where".

> $where = "AND DEV_ID = ".your_supposed_to_be_a_value_here.";

second: if you don't mind, change your variable name into something more relative.

third: assumed query

```
$where = "AND DEV_ID = ".your_supposed_to_be_a_value_here.";
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `".TBL_DEVICE."` WHERE DEV_STATUS='1' $where ORDER BY DEV_TYPE ASC";
```